# dynamic animation of object line with JAVAFX and SceneBuilder

Tags: java, javafx

i'm looking for a system to render this animation of the line dynamic with variable change:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    private long batt = 0;

    @FXML
    private Line lancettaBatteria;

    public long mappa(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max) {
        return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


        Random random = new Random();
        batt = random.nextInt(100);

        long valMappatoBatteria = this.mappa(batt, 0, 100, -40, 135);
        Rotate rotazioneBatteria = new Rotate();

        lancettaBatteria.getTransforms().add(rotazioneBatteria);

        Timeline timelineBatteria = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rotazioneBatteria.angleProperty(), -40)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), new KeyValue(rotazioneBatteria.angleProperty(), valMappatoBatteria)));
        timelineBatteria.play();
}
```

with this code it show only the first random number, my target is to **move** **the** **line** **for** **infinite** **time** **with** **the** **relative** **random** **number** **generated**(i need the random number for display the line in particular position), is this possible? i try to sorround all with a while(true)

```
 public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        while(true){
        Random random = new Random();
        batt = random.nextInt(100);

        long valMappatoBatteria = this.mappa(batt, 0, 100, -40, 135);
        Rotate rotazioneBatteria = new Rotate();

        lancettaBatteria.getTransforms().add(rotazioneBatteria);

        Timeline timelineBatteria = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rotazioneBatteria.angleProperty(), -40)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), new KeyValue(rotazioneBatteria.angleProperty(), valMappatoBatteria)));
        timelineBatteria.play();
        }
}
```

but the app stop to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General Approaches**

In general, an infinite animation in Java can be achieved multiple ways.

Here are a few:

1. Set the [cycle count](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Animation.html#cycleCountProperty) to indefinite to have an animation play forever:

   ```
   Timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
   ```

   Also setAutoReverse to true if you want it to go back and forth.
2. Use an [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html).
3. Use a Timeline and add an onFinished handler to the timeline which updates some relevant Keyframes within the timeline as necessary and then plays the timeline from start again.

The third approach of using an onFinishedHandler is the approach followed in the specific example below.

**Specific Example**

This example is based upon the requirements of your question as I understand them.  I have no idea what why you are trying to do this.  But as far as I understand what you are trying to do, the following app will do it.

Start position of each rotation:

[image: value at start]

Random max position of a rotation:

[image: value at end]

What it does is create a timeline which will update a value in a rotation transform for a line continuously.  The line starts from a starting rotation angle, animates to a random maximum value and then animates back.  Once the line reaches its starting position, a new random maximum value for the rotation is generated and the line animates to this new maximum value and back again.  The process continues indefinitely.  The setOnFinishedHandler of the timeline animation is the point which calculates the new random maximum value and updates the keyframe for the maximum animation value appropriately.

So that may or may not be exactly what you are trying to do, but perhaps it is enough for you to implement what you need.

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.Random;

public class VariableLine extends Application {
    private static final double S = 100;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        RandomRotator randomRotator = new RandomRotator();

        Line line = new Line(0, S, S, S);
        randomRotator.getRotate().setPivotY(S);
        line.getTransforms().add(randomRotator.getRotate());

        Label maxValueText = new Label(randomRotator.getMaxAngle() + "");
        maxValueText.textProperty().bind(randomRotator.maxAngleProperty().asString());

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(maxValueText, line), S, S * 2));
        stage.show();

        randomRotator.getTimeline().play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class RandomRotator {
    private static final Random random = new Random(42);

    private static final double INIT_ANGLE = -40;
    private static final double MAX_ANGLE = 90;
    private static final Duration ROTATION_DURATION = Duration.seconds(3);

    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper maxAngle = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper(INIT_ANGLE);
    private final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    private final Rotate rotate = new Rotate(INIT_ANGLE);

    RandomRotator() {
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
            new KeyFrame(
                    Duration.seconds(0),
                    new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), INIT_ANGLE)
            ),
            new KeyFrame(
                    ROTATION_DURATION.divide(2), 
                    new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), maxAngle.get())
            ),
            new KeyFrame(
                    ROTATION_DURATION,
                    new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), INIT_ANGLE)
            )
        );

        timeline.setOnFinished(event -> {
            maxAngle.set(random.nextInt((int) MAX_ANGLE));
            timeline.getKeyFrames().set(
                    1,
                    new KeyFrame(
                            ROTATION_DURATION.divide(2), 
                            new KeyValue(rotate.angleProperty(), maxAngle.get())
                    )
            );
            timeline.playFromStart();
        });
    }

    Rotate getRotate() {
        return rotate;
    }

    public double getMaxAngle() {
        return maxAngle.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty maxAngleProperty() {
        return maxAngle.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public Timeline getTimeline() {
        return timeline;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but that dont refresh another random number , thanks

Comment: When the value changes, stop the timeline with the old vslue, create a new timeline with the new value and start the new timeline.  Or use the AnimationTimer.

Comment: my target is: move the line for infinite time with the relative random number generated .2 step 1)generate random number 2) make animation for that random number ,and repeat step 1 and 2 ,....